# useMemo vs useRef to avoid rendering memoized components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's say I have the `ExpensiveMemoizedTree` component that's memoized and I'd like to avoid re-rendering it. Still I need to pass a style object to it. Is there a difference between the following two implementations:

```
function App1() {
    const style=useMemo(()=>({color: 'red'}), []);
    return <ExpensiveMemoizedTree style={style}/>
}
```

… and:

```
function App2() {
    const style=useRef({color: 'red'});
    return <ExpensiveMemoizedTree style={style.current}/>
}
```

My understanding is that there's no difference.